# Unable to get latest state value using ngrx in Angular

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-state-managmement

Hello guys I am new to angular. These days I am trying to learn state management in angular. well, I tried following some tutorials but some of their code was already depreciated so I am a bit stuck in a problem. I am unable to get the latest state value in my ts file even after subscribing to it.

```
//Action File
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';

export enum CategoriesActionTypes {
  LoadCategoriess = '[Categories] Load Categoriess',
  LoadCategoriessSuccess = '[Categories] Load Categoriess Success',
  LoadCategoriessFailure = '[Categories] Load Categoriess Failure',
}

export class LoadCategoriess implements Action {
  readonly type = CategoriesActionTypes.LoadCategoriess;
}

export class LoadCategoriessSuccess implements Action {
  readonly type = CategoriesActionTypes.LoadCategoriessSuccess;
  constructor(public payload: { data: any }) { }
}

export class LoadCategoriessFailure implements Action {
  readonly type = CategoriesActionTypes.LoadCategoriessFailure;
  constructor(public payload: { error: any }) { }
}

export type CategoriesActions = LoadCategoriess | LoadCategoriessSuccess | LoadCategoriessFailure;
```

//Reducer file

```
import { CategoriesActions, CategoriesActionTypes } from '../Actions/categories.actions';
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';


export const categoriesFeatureKey = 'categoriesState';

export interface State {
categories :any,
error: any
}

export const initialState: State = {
  categories:[{name:'name'}],
  error :null,
};

export function reducer(state = initialState, action: CategoriesActions): State {
  
  switch (action.type) {
    case CategoriesActionTypes.LoadCategoriess:
    return{
      ...state
    }
    case CategoriesActionTypes.LoadCategoriessSuccess:
      // debugger
      console.log(action.payload.data);
      
      return {
        ...state,
        categories: action.payload.data,
        error: ''
      }

    case CategoriesActionTypes.LoadCategoriessFailure:
      return {
        ...state,
        categories: [],
        error: action.payload.error
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

//Effects File

```
import { FrontserveiceService } from './../front/frontserveice.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, Effect, createEffect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';

import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as CategoriesActions from './../Actions/categories.actions';
import { mergeMap, map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class CategoriesEffects {



  constructor(private actions$: Actions,private service:FrontserveiceService) {}


  // @Effect()
  loadCategories$: Observable<any> = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(CategoriesActions.CategoriesActionTypes.LoadCategoriess),
    mergeMap(
      action => this.service.CategoryList({ image: true }).pipe(
        map(users => {
          return (new CategoriesActions.LoadCategoriessSuccess({ data: users }));
        }),
        catchError(err => of(new CategoriesActions.LoadCategoriessFailure({ error: err })))
      )
    )
  ));
  
}
```

I hope someone can guide me. My angular version is 10.2.

**EDITED**
Subscription

```
this.store.dispatch(new CategoriesActions.LoadCategoriess());
    // console.log(select(fromcategory.getUsers));
    
    this.store.pipe(select(fromcategory.getUsers)).subscribe(
      users => {
        console.log(users);
        this.categories = users.categories;
        this.service.CategoryData = users.categories != undefined ? users.categories : [];
        this.Scategory = this.StoreSelect(this.categories);

      }
    )
    this.store.pipe(select(fromcategory.getError)).subscribe(
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    )
```

[Redux Devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNRps.png)

//Selector

```
import { State } from './../Reducerss/categories.reducer';
import { createFeatureSelector, createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';

const getCategoryFeatureState = createFeatureSelector<State>('categoriesState');

export const getUsers = createSelector(
    getCategoryFeatureState,
    state => state.categories
)

export const getError = createSelector(
    getCategoryFeatureState,
    state => state.error
)
```

Comment: can you share your subscription

Comment: and also a screenshot of state (redux dev tool) will be helpful to understand the problem

Comment: ok let me edit my question for it

Comment: Can you share your selector code?

Comment: Uploaded Selector code

Comment: return (new CategoriesActions.LoadCategoriessSuccess({ data: users.categories })); change your LoadSuccess action inside effects something like and try

Comment: @Chellappanவ I tried it. It doesn't work, Subscription code works on its first running after that it doesn't trigger even if the state gets changed.

Comment: Are you getting any error?  categories property in state is  intially  array, but it was overriden to object when you dispatch success action

Comment: No there are no errors subscribe function is running before the API call which is returning the initial state but when the API call gets completed the code doesn't trigger again and there lies the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it now. I was trying to access a portion of the state which is not allowed that's why I was unable to access the state in the subscription.